# Обработчик 'onclick' не переходит на следующий элемент

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код, задача в том чтобы обработчик 'onclick' переходил на следующую строку таблицы. 
console.log(row) показывает, что переменная 'row' успешно меняется, но 'onclick' остаётся на прежнем ряду таблицы.
Как исправить?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //о передвижении по рядам
  var w = 0;
  var row =  $('.row'+w);
  
   row.children().on('click', function(){
       var clicked = $(this); 
       var color = ['green', 'red', 'green'];
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
       clicked.css({'backgroundColor' : color[rand]});
       w=w+1;
       row =  $('.row'+w);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr class="row0">
  <td class="cell">1-1</td>
  <td class="cell" >1-2</td>
  <td class="cell">1-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row1">
  <td class="cell1">2-1</td>
  <td class="cell1">2-2</td>
  <td class="cell1">2-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class= "row2">
  <td class="cell2">3-1</td>
  <td class="cell2">3-2</td>
  <td class="cell2">3-3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //о передвижении по рядам
  var w = 0;
  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];

  $("tr[class^='row'] td").on('click', function() {
    if (!$('.row' + w).is($(this).closest("tr")))
      return;

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
    $(this).css({ 'backgroundColor': colors[index] });

    w = (w + 1) % 3;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row0">
    <td class="cell">1-1</td>
    <td class="cell">1-2</td>
    <td class="cell">1-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td class="cell1">2-1</td>
    <td class="cell1">2-2</td>
    <td class="cell1">2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td class="cell2">3-1</td>
    <td class="cell2">3-2</td>
    <td class="cell2">3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант работает! Могли бы объяснить, что делает этот фрагмент if (!$('.row' + w).is($(this).closest("tr")))
      return; ?

Comment: @orel-22 Как Вы видите, обработчик `click` назначается всем клеткам. Но внутри мы проверяем, соответствует ли ряд-родитель щелкнутой клетки тому ряду, который мы считаем текущим по значению `w`.

Comment: @orel-22 Если не соответствует, то ничего не делаем - выходим.

Comment: Всё понял. Спасибо!